# Does a set which is composed only from itself is countable?

Tags: set-theory

Consider a set which only has 1 element - itself : $A=\{A\}$. If we expand this set, we get $A=\{\{\{\ldots \{_n A \}_n\ldots\}\}\}$ where $n \to \infty$. So it seems that we can't get the reference of what set element points to. Does this make such set uncountable ?

Comment: You seem to mean $A=\{A\}$, not $(A).$ And $A=\{\{\{\dots\{A\}\dots\}\}\}$ with an arbitrary large (but finite) number of $\{\},$ not "$(((\ldots (_n A )_n\ldots)))$ where $n \to \infty$". That said: the answer is "yes, of course: every singleton is countable".

Comment: Yes, curly braces, just when I edited my question somehow engine was not parsing/rendering escaped braces. I don't get why brace number is finite,- it should be endless recursion, i.e. closed loop ?

Comment: Does the engine allow you to edit those braces now? Brace number is finite because only that kind of formula has a defined meaning. One hour ago when looking for some duplicate, I found some related answer from @AsafKaragila beginning with something like "writing something is not sufficient to make it exist", but I lost the page.

Comment: Yes, It allows now, I've fixed latex. But if we will terminate the brace expansion,- the definition of set will technically not be $A=\{A\}$, because finite levels of recursion, must be included in the definition itself, or not ?

Comment: None of the equalities $A=\{A\},$ $A=\{\{A\}\},$ etc. are *definitions* of $A$, but if (for some hypothetical $A$) the first one holds, then all do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that "ordinary" set theory prohibits the existence of such sets. ZFC contains the axiom of foundation, which says that there cannot be an infinite descending chain of sets $\cdots \in X_3 \in X_2 \in X_1 \in X_0$. (If your set existed, it would provide an infinite chain: we would have $\cdots \in A \in A \in A$.)

However, we can ignore the axiom of foundation for this question: yes, such a set would be countable. Whether or not a set is countable depends only on whether its elements can inject into the set of natural numbers. The "content" of the elements is irrelevant. For example, the one-element set $\{\mathbb R\}$ is also countable. It contains precisely one element, and it doesn't matter that its one element is itself an uncountable set. Similarly, your set $A$ consists of one element (which is $A$ itself). It doesn't matter *what* that element is, it already follows that $A$ is countable. In fact, it is finite.